# JCIP SafePoint - is it really thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz et al there is the following example (listing 4.11 shortened).

```
public class SafePoint {
private int x, y;
public SafePoint(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public synchronized int[] get() {
    return new int[] { x, y };
}

public synchronized void set(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

}

Is it really thread-safe? x and y are neither volatile nor final, and they are set without locking on this which means another thread invoking get() may see stale values (zeros). Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it really thread-safe?

Yes.

> x and y are neither volatile nor final,

Correct, but ....

> and they are set without locking on this

Incorrect.  The get and set methods are `synchronized` methods which means that they *implicitly* lock and synchronize on `this`.

---

Actually ... there is a caveat to this.  There must also be a *happens before* between the creation of the `SafePoint` instance and the (first) `get` or `set` call on some other thread.  If there isn't, then it is possible that the `get` or `set` might see the default values for `x` and `y` rather than the values passed to the constructor.

*Goetz et al* covers this on the next page of Java Concurrency in Practice ... though they use higher level reasoning than *hb* relationships.  In listing 4.12 they use a `ConcurrentHashMap` to ensure that the `SafePoint` is *safely published*.